# cannot update android sdk tools to rev19

Tags: android, eclipse-indigo

I have downloaded the GoogleAPI and it says that I must update the android sdk tools. I am doing this inside sdk manager and I get this error:

```
Failed to rename directory C:\Users\Me\android-sdks\platform-tools to C:\Users\Me\android-sdks\temp\PlatformToolPackage.old01.
Skipping 'Android SDK Tools, revision 19'; it depends on 'Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 11' which was not installed.
```

any suggestion?

I am using eclipse indigo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've seen this on several computers lately.  You might have luck messing with the folder or rebooting... but you are better off uninstalling/reinstalling the Android SDK, which always works.

Comment: Windows 7 I was getting same error ran as admin fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue a long time ago whereby the SDKManager invokes tools/android.bat. This means it is impossible for it to move the file. Absurd to the max but copy paste the tools directory with a different name and run it from there. Worked for me

Failing that check out the link at [Can't upgrade Android SDK Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559682/cant-upgrade-android-sdk-tools)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue every time i update. I reboot in safe mode with network and then it goes without any problems. Hope it helps. B