# android - updating ADT

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-adt

I want to update the ADT in Eclipse. For this i go to Help->CheckforUpdates->I got the following error. How to solve this. Why it's came.please can anybody help me.

**Error Window**

[image]

**Eclipse Properties**

[image]

Comment: Update your SDK. If it is already upgraded, then upgrade your eclipse IDE.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8559764/1012284

Answer (score 0):

first of all install right Android SDK and install on of version (according to your need like 4.0.3).

then continue your upgradation of ADT.