# Return to previous configuration in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I tried using the Eclipse option to return to a previous state. I mean, I install Maven package today and I want to return to the settings before installing Eclipse Maven package.

For this option go to Help / About Eclipse / Instalation details / Instalation history and there therefore selected the version you want to go back and Revert pulse.

When I do this after a while you get the following error:

**An error occurred while collecting items to be installed**

```
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt,16.0.1.v201112150204-238534
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt,16.0.1.v201112150204-238534
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms,16.0.1.v201112150204-238534
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms,16.0.1.v201112150204-238534
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer,16.0.1.v201112150204-238534
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer,16.0.1.v201112150204-238534
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview,16.0.1.v201112150204-238534
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview,16.0.1.v201112150204-238534
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.hibernate.eclipse.feature,3.4.0.v20111213-1944-H40-M5
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay,16.0.1.v201112150204-238534
```

Do you know it can be and how to fix it?

I have to return to the previous state

Comment: actually you are using galileo eclipse 3.5 you need 3.6 helios or indigo 3.7 to install new android plugins. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8559764/1012284

Comment: No, my version is the following: Version: Indigo Service Release 2