# Pulldown control on Android 2.3.3 (API10)

Tags: android

I am developing an app in which the main display needs to be as uncluttered as possible, but with quick and easy access to menu controls.
What I would like to implement is similar to the main pulldown control (for Data, WiFi, BT on/off and so on) but am unsure what would be the best way to go about it.
I'm very new to Android and quite new to Java (not to programming in general, although my main focus is embedded development in C) so aside from a complete answer, any basic advice would be most appreciated.

Comment: Search a bit around for [SlidingDrawer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html) examples, maybe that's what you are looking for.

Comment: @alextsc - thanks, I'm looking now, seems to be what I'm after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See my example here](https://mobibear.wordpress.com/2010/07/12/android-slidingdrawer-with-custom-view/). Its uses the sliding drawer with a custom view.

Comment: Had a couple of build issues, it was late so I went off to sleep. Just looking again now, will update you as soon as I know more...

Comment: I (think I) needed to update the SDK, so I'm currently having fun with [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559682/cant-upgrade-android-sdk-tools).... Copying the folder didn't work for me, so I'm just installing again.

Comment: Okay, managed to get it running and it seems to be just what I need - just need to tweak it for my app. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's called a Sliding Drawer. Look at the examples online and follow the documentation, you will be fine.