# Android Studio : monitor.exe has stopped working

Tags: android, android-studio, ddms

**Backgruond :**

IDE : *Android Studio 0.8.9.*

I know that ddms was depracted and Android Studio Actually use **monitor.exe**.

Note : The ddms mork for me.

**What I have tried**

The same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16635424/android-studio-cannot-open-monitor-ddms) already was asked and the solution was to set path enviroment with **jdk/jre** location, but i'm already set my path with jre and jdk but nothing changed.

Comment: @Which Platform u r using linux/windows

Comment: @SpryTechies windows

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=55504 an issue already registered please do have a look

Comment: I tried to run it with admin privileges but not worked

Comment: yes it have some issues

Comment: @SpryTechies try to update your Android SDK tools it worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to Update your Android SDK Tools to the last version.